# Laravel 5.1 - make input editor text

Tags: html, forms, laravel

I have a form to create my article, my template have a editor like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Text areas<small>Sessions</small></h2>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">


                  <div id="alerts"></div>
                  <div class="btn-toolbar editor" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">

                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    </div>
                  <div id="editor"> 

                  HERE MY EDITOR CREATE THE CODE HTML bold,color,font-size.

                  I WOULD LIKE INSERT A INPUT HERE

                  </div>

                  <textarea name="descr" id="descr" style="display:none;"></textarea>
                  <br />

                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Resizable Text area</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                      <textarea class="resizable_textarea form-control" placeholder="This text area automatically resizes its height as you fill in more text courtesy of autosize-master it out..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

My editor create a code HTML, like this:

```
<div id="editor"> 

<b>
<font face="Comic Sans MS">THIS IS A TEXT CREATED BY MY EDITOR</font>
</b>
</div>
```

I would like insert a input here, how can i do it?

I tried like this:

```
<div id="editor"> 
      <input>  
    <b>
    <font face="Comic Sans MS">THIS IS A TEXT CREATED BY MY EDITOR</font>
    </b>
     </input> 
 </div>
```

but it doesn't work well, it creates an input outside of text area.

Comment: you want the text 'This is my text created by my editor' inside the box right?

Comment: What are things related to Laravel here?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin yes right!

Answer (score -2):

It's simple bro, do it like this

```
<input placeholder="THIS IS A TEXT CREATED BY MY EDITOR">  
</input>
```

Or You can also use value

```
<input value="THIS IS A TEXT CREATED BY MY EDITOR">  
</input>
```